# Opencv: how to create new matrix from existing matrix with some changes?

Tags: opencv, matrix, copy, repeat

in OpenCV, I have a matrix like this: [3 4 2; 5 2 1; 6 7 9], that is with 3x3 size. Now I want to change it into 3x1 size, and be like this: 
[3 4 2 5 2 1 6 7 9]. But this is not exactly what I want, my actual goal is to put zero before and after each value, at the same time repeat each value three times. So my goal matrix should be like this: [ 0 3 3 3 0 0 4 4 4 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 5 5 5 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 6 6 6 0 0 7 7 7 0 0 9 9 9 0 ]. I wrote the following code for this:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i ++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < 3; j ++ )
        {               
                for ( int m = k + 1; m < m + 3; m ++ )
                {
                    dstMat.col (m) = srcMat.at <int> ( i, j );

                }

                k = k + 5 ;                 
        }
    }
```

Is there any better way for doing is? Especially without "for" loop, it is really time confusing. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Mat::reshape](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=#Mat%20Mat%3a%3areshape%28int%20cn,%20int%20rows%29%20const) to convert your 3x3 matrix to 3x1. This way you'll need one for loop instead of two, and it's an `O(1)` operation.

you can omit the next for loop by using ROI:

```
  srcMat.reshape(0,1);
  for (int i =0; i < 9; i++)
    dstMat(cv::Range::all(), cv::Range(i*5+1, i*5+4)).setTo(srcMat.at<int>(i));
```

and that would be all.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The line "srcMat.reshape(0,1)" does not work, but if I change it into "srcMat.reshape(1,0)" it works. But that is different from what I want. Do you know what could be the reason? I am reading a video frame here as srcMat.

Comment: The first parameter is number of channels in the new matrix, and the second parameter is number of rows. when you specify zero for the second parameter you're still stuck with a 3x3 mat. the problem might be with something elese, are you sure the source matrix has `int` type?

Comment: The source matrix is of "CV_8U" type. Any ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: for `CV_8U` use `srcMat.at<unsigned char>(i)`

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. I changed as you said. But I found the problem is the line " srcMat.reshape(0,1)". My currently using "srcMat" is of 800x600 size. Any suggestion?

Comment: Dear Mohammad, the reshape part is ok now, but the problem is in the for loop. My resulted dstMat is all zeros. My srcMat is not a zero matrix. Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: I just found that the resulted dstMat is nonzero only in the for loop, but outside, it is all zero. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: cv::Mat previousFrame ( 800, 600, CV_8UC3, previousFrame );
cv::Mat capturedFrame ( 800, 600, CV_8UC3, currentFrame );
cv::Mat subtractedFrame = subtract ( previousFrame, capturedFrame);
cv::Mat medianMat;
cv::Mat dstMat;
cv::medianBlur (subtractedFrame, medianMat, 5 );
cv::Mat reshapedMedianMat = medianMat.reshape ( 0, 1 );

for ( int i = 0; i < reshapedMedianMat.cols; i ++ )
{
dstMat ( cv::Range::all(), cv::Range ( i * 5 + 1, i * 5 + 4 )).setTo ( reshapedMedianMat.at <int>(i));
}

Answer (score 0):

You could start by calling [reshape](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html) on your matrix to flatten it to one row/column.  That would save you one of the for loops and make it slightly clearer.