# reshaping a matrix failed in OpenCV 2.4.3

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, resize

I am using OpenCV 2.4.3 to create and reshape a matrix like this:

```
cv::Mat testMat = cv::Mat::zeros ( 500, 200, CV_8UC3 );
std::cout << "size of testMat: " << testMat.rows << " x " << testMat.cols << std::endl;

testMat.reshape ( 0, 1 );
std::cout << " size of reshaped testMat: " << testMat.rows << " x " << testMat.cols << std::endl;
```

Then from the output, I see there is no change for the reshaped testMat. I used "reshape" many times in older version of OpenCV, but with this new version, I couldn't see any changes. Is this a bug? Or am I using it incorrectly here?

Comment: reshape's parameters are (cn,rows), where cn is the number of channels

Comment: What are you wanting it to do?

Comment: yes I know, but when I used it like this in 2.4.2 version, I got exactly what I want. By the way then, how could I still get "500x200" size here then?

Comment: I want it for testing "reshape" command in this version.

Comment: You want a matrix with no channels?

Comment: I see, the zero is supposed to indicate that it stays the same.

Comment: So you want a matrix that has the same number of channels, but only one row?

Comment: please take a look at this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883461/opencv-how-to-create-new-matrix-from-existing-matrix-with-some-changes

Comment: the result still is the same with "ones" or any other input values, for instance from an image.

Comment: Yes, I need only one row with the same num of channels. After reshaping, I was expecting to see its size as 1x100000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

reshape returns a new Mat header

```
cv::Mat testMat = cv::Mat::zeros ( 500, 200, CV_8UC3 );
std::cout << "size of testMat: " << testMat.rows << " x " << testMat.cols << std::endl;

cv::Mat result = testMat.reshape ( 0, 1 );
std::cout << " size of original testMat: " << testMat.rows << " x " << testMat.cols << std::endl;
std::cout << " size of reshaped testMat: " << result.rows << " x " << result.cols << std::endl;
```