# OpenCV: Mat::reshape() does nothing

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a `640 x 480 CV_8UC3` `Mat image` and want to perform the k-means segmentation. So I need to convert it to `CV_32F` (no problem here), reshape it, and run k-means.

The problem is `reshape()` does nothing:

```
cv::Mat colorMat;
image.convertTo (colorMat, CV_32FC3);
std::cout << colorMat.size () << "; ch: " << colorMat.channels () << std::endl; // [640 x 480]; ch: 3
colorMat.reshape (1, colorMat.rows * colorMat.cols); // Here I expect it to become [307200 x 3], 1 channel - each column representing a color component
std::cout << colorMat.size () << "; ch: " << colorMat.channels () << std::endl; // [640 x 480]; ch: 3
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to assign the result of `reshape`to a matrix:

```
colorMat = colorMat.reshape (1, colorMat.rows * colorMat.cols);
```

You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34734939/5008845) (second snippet) a complete example.

Comment: Yes, I was just writing a similar answer having read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400239/reshaping-a-matrix-failed-in-opencv-2-4-3). They lack the return value descriptions in the documentation obviously...

Comment: Actually the [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a4eb96e3251417fa88b78e2abd6cfd7d8) shows that the return value is a `Mat`, but probably it's not clear enough.